# Why do i get the "Could not autowire. No beans of 'PersonService' type found."-error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am using `Spring Boot` and I'm trying to create a `REST` api, but I can't resolve this error:

> "Could not autowire. No beans of 'PersonService' type found."

So in my project I have the following structure:

```
▼ com.example
  ▼ person
    ▼ controller
        PersonController (class)
    ► dao
    ► datasouurce
    ► model
    ▼ service
        PersonService (class)
  ► car
  CarApplication (Spring Boot runnable class)
```

I had a project with only the 'car' folder and the `CarApplication.class` was inside the 'car' folder and everything worked fine. Now i added the Person folder to the project and moved the `CarApplication.class` one level up because now it has to handle both 'car' and 'person'. But since doing that I get an error in `PersonController.class`.

This is my PersonService.class:

```
package com.example.person.service;

import ...

public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    public PersonService(@Qualifier("postgres") PersonDao personDao) {
         this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personDao.selectAllPersons();
    }

    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(UUID id) {
        return personDao.selectPersonById(id);
    }
}
```

This is the `CarApplication.class`:

```
package com.example;

import ...

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAdminServer
public class CarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And last, but not least, this is my `PersonController.class` where the error occurs:

```
package com.example.person.controller;

import ...

@RequestMapping("api/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService **personService**) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personService.getAllPersons();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}")
    public Person getPersonById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
        return personService.getPersonById(id)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

I have surrounded the variable that throws the error with "**" in the `PersonController.class`.

This is my datasource properties from application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/persondb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I have tried to use `@ComponentScan` to specify which maps should be scanned for beans, but it doesn't solve it. Also it should already scan the correct files since the `CarApplication.class` has been moved up.  If more info is needed please let me know.

**UPDATE:**
I have added the `@Service` on top of the `PersonService.class` and it actually removed the red underlining of the eventService variable in `PersonController.class`. But when I run the `CarApplication` it still says:

```
Error creating bean with name 'eventService' defined in file [C:\...\com\capasystems\person\service\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postgres' defined in file [C:\...\com\capasystems\person\dao\PersonDataAccessService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

Comment: Show your datasource properties from application.yml (or .properties). Do you use Flyway? If not then you must turn its auto-configuration off

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko
Done! I use Flyway.

Comment: Try to add datasource property `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver` and add Postrges driver artifact into your dependencies (if missing)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko
I already have the Postgres driver artifact in my dependencies, so I added the datasource property to my application.properties, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you launch Spring application with non-default profile, that has no configured datasource properties?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko 
I only have one profile which is default.

Comment: Then maybe flyway properties are missing? Like `spring.flyway.url / spring.flyway.user / spring.flyway.password`. I'm not sure if they are inherited from spring's datasource properties

Answer (score 2):

you need @Service in top of your Person service class

```
package com.example.person.service;

import ...

@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    public PersonService(@Qualifier("postgres") PersonDao personDao) {
         this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personDao.selectAllPersons();
    }

    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(UUID id) {
        return personDao.selectPersonById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I've updated the post please check the bottom.

Comment: check your postgres connection it seems the service is not available.

Comment: The connection is fine, I have no problem connecting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `@ComponentScan` ?

```java
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAdminServer
@ComponentScan({ "aaa.bbb.ccc.*" })
public class Application {}
```

Make sure you have `@Repository` and `@Service` appropriately annotated also make sure all your packages are under `aaa.bbb.ccc.`
In most cases, this setup resolves these kinds of issues.

Let me know the result.

Comment: Yes I have the annotations, except for the ComponentScan annotation. SpringBootApplication already has this annotation within it, so if i add ComponentScan it gives me an error saying that it is redundant.

Comment: It's strange, maybe something is missing from `pom.xml`. Because it throws `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`.